# iOS MDM SCEP PKIOperation: The SCEP server returned an invalid response

Tags: ios, node.js, mdm, scep

**Preface**

I am working on implementing an iOS MDM server in Node.js and using [node-forge](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge) for PKI. Part of Device Enrollment requires the use of SCEP.

**Issue**
Devices are currently failing at the initial `operation=PKIOperation` CSR request to my server. The error message seen from the devices is rather vague:

```
May 18 14:39:46 iPad-2 Preferences[27999] <Notice>: (Error) MC: Install profile data, interactive error. Error: NSError:
    Desc   : Profile Installation Failed
    Sugg   : The SCEP server returned an invalid response.
    US Desc: Profile Installation Failed
    US Sugg: The SCEP server returned an invalid response.
    Domain : MCInstallationErrorDomain
    Code   : 4001
    Type   : MCFatalError
    ...Underlying error:
    NSError:
    Desc   : The SCEP server returned an invalid response.
    US Desc: The SCEP server returned an invalid response.
    Domain : MCSCEPErrorDomain
    Code   : 22013
    Type   : MCFatalError
    Extra info:
    {
        isPrimary = 1;
    }
```

I have attempted to model my CSR handling based on [Simple Certificate Enrollment Protocol Overview](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security-vpn/public-key-infrastructure-pki/116167-technote-scep-00.html) and the following Ruby sample code ([found here](https://github.com/nolanbrown/ios-cert-enrollment/blob/master/lib/ios-cert-enrollment/sign.rb) and elsewhere):

```
def sign_PKI(data)
    p7sign = OpenSSL::PKCS7.new(data)
    store = OpenSSL::X509::Store.new
    p7sign.verify(nil, store, nil, OpenSSL::PKCS7::NOVERIFY)
    signers = p7sign.signers
    p7enc = OpenSSL::PKCS7.new(p7sign.data)

    # Certificate Signing Request
    csr = p7enc.decrypt(SSL.key, SSL.certificate)

    # Signed Certificate
    cert = self.sign_certificate(csr)

    degenerate_pkcs7 = OpenSSL::PKCS7.new()
    degenerate_pkcs7.type="signed"
    degenerate_pkcs7.certificates=[cert]
    enc_cert = OpenSSL::PKCS7.encrypt(p7sign.certificates, degenerate_pkcs7.to_der, 
        OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher::new("des-ede3-cbc"), OpenSSL::PKCS7::BINARY)
    reply = OpenSSL::PKCS7.sign(SSL.certificate, SSL.key, enc_cert.to_der, [], OpenSSL::PKCS7::BINARY)

    return Certificate.new(reply.to_der, "application/x-pki-message")        
end
```

Finally, here is my implementation using Node.js and node-forge:

```
function pkiOperationScepOperationHandler(req, reply) {
    //
    //  |req.query.message| should contain a Base64 encoded PKCS#7 package.
    //  The SignedData portion is PKCS#7 EnvelopedData encrypted with the CA
    //  public key we gave the client in GetCACert. Once decrypted, we have
    //  ourselves the client's CSR.
    //
    if(!req.query.message) {
        return reply('The CA could not validate the request').code(403);
    }

    const msgBuffer = new Buffer(req.query.message, 'base64');

    let p7Message;
    try {
        p7Message = forge.pkcs7.messageFromAsn1(
            forge.asn1.fromDer(
                forge.util.createBuffer(msgBuffer, 'binary')
            )
        );

        const p7EnvelopedData = forge.pkcs7.messageFromAsn1(
            forge.asn1.fromDer(
                forge.util.createBuffer(new Buffer(p7Message.rawCapture.content.value[0].value[0].value, 'binary'), 'binary')
            )
        );

        p7EnvelopedData.decrypt(p7EnvelopedData.recipients[0], conf.serverConfig.caPrivateKey);

        //  p7EnvelopedData should contain a PKCS#10 CSR
        const csrDataBuffer = new Buffer(p7EnvelopedData.content.getBytes(), 'binary');
        const csr = forge.pki.certificationRequestFromAsn1(
            forge.asn1.fromDer(
                forge.util.createBuffer(csrDataBuffer, 'binary')
            ),
            true    //  computeHash
        );

        //
        //  Create a new cert based on the CSR and sign it
        //
        //  See https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge/issues/154
        //
        const signedCert = forge.pki.createCertificate();
        signedCert.serialNumber             = Date.now().toString();
        signedCert.validity.notBefore       = new Date();
        signedCert.validity.notAfter        = new Date();
        signedCert.validity.notAfter.setFullYear(signedCert.validity.notBefore.getFullYear() + 1);

        signedCert.setSubject(csr.subject.attributes);
        signedCert.setIssuer(conf.serverConfig.caCert.subject.attributes);

        signedCert.setExtensions([
            {
                name                            : 'keyUsage',
                digitalSignature    : true,
                keyEncipherment     : true,
            }
        ]);


        signedCert.publicKey = csr.publicKey;
        signedCert.sign(conf.serverConfig.caPrivateKey);

        const degenerate = forge.pkcs7.createSignedData();
        degenerate.addCertificate(signedCert);

        const enveloped = forge.pkcs7.createEnvelopedData();

        // UPDATE 1
        enveloped.recipients.push({
          version: 0,
          issuer: csr.subject.attributes,
          serialNumber: signedCert.serialNumber,
          encryptedContent: {
            algorithm: forge.pki.oids.rsaEncryption,
            key: csr.publicKey
          }
        });

        enveloped.content = forge.asn1.toDer(degenerate.toAsn1());
        enveloped.encryptedContent.algorithm = forge.pki.oids['des-EDE3-CBC'];
        enveloped.encrypt();

        const signed = forge.pkcs7.createSignedData();
        signed.addCertificate(conf.serverConfig.caCert);
        signed.addSigner({
            key                                 : conf.serverConfig.caPrivateKey,
            certificate                 : conf.serverConfig.caCert,
            digestAlgorithm         : forge.pki.oids.sha1,
            authenticatedAttributes : [
                {
                    type    : forge.pki.oids.contentType,
                    value   : forge.pki.oids.data
                },
                {
                    type: forge.pki.oids.messageDigest              
                },
                {
                    type: forge.pki.oids.signingTime,               
                },              
            ] 
        });

        signed.content = forge.asn1.toDer(enveloped.toAsn1());
        signed.sign();

        const signedDer = new Buffer(forge.asn1.toDer(signed.toAsn1()).getBytes(), 'binary');                   
        return reply(signedDer).bytes(signedDer.length).type('application/x-pki-message');
    } catch(e) {
        req.log( ['error' ], { message : e.toString() } );
        return reply('The CA could not validate the request').code(403);
    }
}
```

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong here?

**Update 1**:
Updated code above to reflect my latest. Still not working, but I believe the recipient information is now correct. (See `UPDATE 1` above)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally got this working (and on to the next SCEP related headache!):

**Overview of problems in original code**:

- Recipient MUST be the cert that signed the *request*: `p7Message.certificates[0]`
- SCEP defines some Authenticated attributes that MUST be present. Of those, `transactionID` and `senderNonce` from the original request must be sent back (`senderNonce` is sent back as `recipientNonce`)
- The OIDs for the SCEP specific attributes are not currently supported by `node-forge`. This required a very simple hack (See [PKCS#7 signed data and custom authenticatedAttributes / OIDs](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge/issues/400))

**Updated working code**:
Below is some updated & working code (note that there are still some missing checks that need to be implemented for validation/etc.)

```
function pkiOperationScepOperationHandler(req, reply) {
    //
    //  |req.query.message| should contain a Base64 encoded PKCS#7 package.
    //  The SignedData portion is PKCS#7 EnvelopedData encrypted with the CA
    //  public key we gave the client in GetCACert. Once decrypted, we have
    //  ourselves the client's CSR.
    //
    if(!req.query.message) {
        return reply('The CA could not validate the request').code(403);
    }

    try {
        const msgBuffer = new Buffer(req.query.message, 'base64');

        const p7Message = forge.pkcs7.messageFromAsn1(
            forge.asn1.fromDer(
                forge.util.createBuffer(msgBuffer, 'binary')
            )
        );

        //  :TODO: Validate integrity
        //  :TODO: Validated signing

        //
        //  The outter PKCS#7 signed data must contain authenticated
        //  attributes for transactionID and senderNonce. We will use these
        //  in our reply back as part of the SCEP spec.
        //
        const oids = forge.pki.oids;
        let origTransactionId = p7Message.rawCapture.authenticatedAttributes.find( attr => {
            const oid = forge.asn1.derToOid(attr.value[0].value);
            return ('2.16.840.1.113733.1.9.7' === oid); //  transactionID
        });

        if(!origTransactionId) {
            return reply('Invalid request payload').code(403);
        }

        origTransactionId = origTransactionId.value[1].value[0].value;  //  PrintableString

        let origSenderNonce = p7Message.rawCapture.authenticatedAttributes.find( attr => {
            const oid = forge.asn1.derToOid(attr.value[0].value);
            return ('2.16.840.1.113733.1.9.5' === oid); //  senderNonce
        });

        if(!origSenderNonce) {
            return reply('Invalid request payload').code(403);
        }

        origSenderNonce = origSenderNonce.value[1].value[0].value;  //  OctetString

        const p7EnvelopedData = forge.pkcs7.messageFromAsn1(
            forge.asn1.fromDer(
                forge.util.createBuffer(new Buffer(p7Message.rawCapture.content.value[0].value[0].value, 'binary'), 'binary')
            )
        );

        //  decrypt using our key
        p7EnvelopedData.decrypt(p7EnvelopedData.recipients[0], conf.serverConfig.caPrivateKey);

        //  p7EnvelopedData should contain a PKCS#10 CSR
        const csrDataBuffer = new Buffer(p7EnvelopedData.content.getBytes(), 'binary');
        const csr = forge.pki.certificationRequestFromAsn1(
            forge.asn1.fromDer(
                forge.util.createBuffer(csrDataBuffer, 'binary')
            ),
            true    //  computeHash
        );      

        //
        //  Create a new cert based on the CSR and sign it
        //
        //  See https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge/issues/154
        //
        const signedCert = forge.pki.createCertificate();
        signedCert.serialNumber             = Date.now().toString();
        signedCert.validity.notBefore       = new Date();
        signedCert.validity.notAfter        = new Date();
        //  expires one year from now (client should contact us before then to renew)
        signedCert.validity.notAfter.setFullYear(signedCert.validity.notBefore.getFullYear() + 1);

        signedCert.setSubject(csr.subject.attributes);
        signedCert.setIssuer(conf.serverConfig.caCert.subject.attributes);

        //  :TODO: Really, this should come from requested extensions in the CSR
        signedCert.setExtensions([
            {
                name                            : 'keyUsage',
                digitalSignature    : true,
                keyEncipherment     : true,
                critical                    : true,
            }
        ]);

        signedCert.publicKey = csr.publicKey;
        signedCert.sign(conf.serverConfig.caPrivateKey);

        req.log( ['trace' ], { message : 'Signed CSR certificate', cert : forge.pki.certificateToPem(signedCert) } );

        const degenerate = forge.pkcs7.createSignedData();
        degenerate.addCertificate(signedCert);
        degenerate.sign();

        const enveloped = forge.pkcs7.createEnvelopedData();

        //  Recipient is the original requester cert
        enveloped.addRecipient(p7Message.certificates[0]);                  
        enveloped.content                       = forge.asn1.toDer(degenerate.toAsn1());
        enveloped.encryptedContent.algorithm    = forge.pki.oids['des-EDE3-CBC'];   //  We set this in GetCACaps
        enveloped.encrypt();

        //  Package up everything in PKCS#7 signed (by us) data
        const signed = forge.pkcs7.createSignedData();  
        signed.addSigner({
            key                     : conf.serverConfig.caPrivateKey,
            certificate             : conf.serverConfig.caCert,
            digestAlgorithm         : forge.pki.oids.sha1,
            authenticatedAttributes : [
                {
                    type    : forge.pki.oids.contentType,
                    value   : forge.pki.oids.data
                },
                {
                    type: forge.pki.oids.messageDigest              
                },
                {
                    type: forge.pki.oids.signingTime,               
                },
                {
                    name    : 'transactionID',
                    type    : '2.16.840.1.113733.1.9.7',
                    rawValue : forge.asn1.create(
                        forge.asn1.Class.UNIVERSAL, 
                        forge.asn1.Type.PRINTABLESTRING, 
                        false, 
                        origTransactionId
                        ),                  
                },
                {
                    name    : 'messageType',
                    type    : '2.16.840.1.113733.1.9.2',
                    rawValue : forge.asn1.create(
                        forge.asn1.Class.UNIVERSAL, 
                        forge.asn1.Type.PRINTABLESTRING, 
                        false, 
                        '3' //  CertRep
                        ),          
                },
                {
                    name    : 'senderNonce',
                    type    : '2.16.840.1.113733.1.9.5',
                    rawValue : forge.asn1.create(
                        forge.asn1.Class.UNIVERSAL, 
                        forge.asn1.Type.OCTETSTRING, 
                        false, 
                        forge.util.createBuffer(forge.random.getBytes(16)).bytes()
                        ),
                },
                {
                    name    : 'recipientNonce',
                    type    : '2.16.840.1.113733.1.9.6',
                    rawValue : forge.asn1.create(
                        forge.asn1.Class.UNIVERSAL, 
                        forge.asn1.Type.OCTETSTRING, 
                        false, 
                        origSenderNonce),
                },  
                {
                    name    : 'pkiStatus',
                    type    : '2.16.840.1.113733.1.9.3',
                    rawValue : forge.asn1.create(
                        forge.asn1.Class.UNIVERSAL, 
                        forge.asn1.Type.PRINTABLESTRING, 
                        false, 
                        '0' //  SUCCESS
                        ),
                }
            ] 
        });

        signed.content = forge.asn1.toDer(enveloped.toAsn1());
        signed.sign();

        const signedDer = new Buffer(forge.asn1.toDer(signed.toAsn1()).getBytes(), 'binary');

        return reply(signedDer).bytes(signedDer.length).type('application/x-pki-message');
    } catch(e) {
        req.log( ['error' ], { message : e.toString() } );
        return reply('The CA could not validate the request').code(403);
    }       
}
```

This took a few days to get right. Hopefully it can be of help to someone!